# Renaming a variable using pipe operator in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using pipe operator to rename a variable. But I am not able to rename it. I know I can do this directly. But it should be possible with pipe operator.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars%>%
    rename(mile=mpg)
```

Comment: `mtcars%>% rename(mile=mpg)` renames and uses a pipe operator. What do you need?

Comment: @Ronak Shah I am getting this Error in rename(., mile = mpg) : unused argument (mile = mpg)

Comment: Try `mtcars%>% dplyr::rename(mile=mpg)`

Comment: You've loaded `plyr` after `dplyr`.  Start again with a fresh R session and load `plyr` first if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Suggestions of various contributors, you should first detach the dplyr and plyr package. Then first load plyr package and then load dplyr or otherwise simply follow other advice.

```
detach(package:plyr,unload = TRUE)
detach(package:dplyr,unload = TRUE)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
mtcars%>%
    rename(mile=mpg)
## other solution
mtcars%>%
   dplyr::rename(mile=mpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars%>%
    rename("mile" = mpg)
```